# MySql wont start in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I know this question has been asked several times, I have looked through other answers but couldn't find the solution.
Last night MySQL was working fine on my XAMPP. Today, When I started MySQL from control panel, it started for a brief moment and then stopped immediately.
I tried again but same thing happened.I completely stopped XAMPP from task manager and restarted again but no use.
I checked if some other application is using port 80 at [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/) but its giving an error,means port 80 is free.
BTW Apache is running fine.
Control panel log says "MySql started", but it stops immediately after that.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use port `80` by default. It uses `3306`. Paste MySQL Logs from XAMPP Controller, use pastebin.com to paste logs.

Comment: Here is the error log  [MySQL log](http://pastebin.com/mt5RT7KS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP setup - MySQL not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163563/xampp-setup-mysql-not-working)

Comment: so you mean I should uninstall and reinstall XAMPP again?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP worked for me.
MySql is running now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps;
1. Open C:\xampp on your device
2. Select xampp_stop.exe
3. Select xampp_start.exe
4. Right click on xampp_stop.exe and select 'Run as Administrator'
5. Select the marked button to install or re-install mysql.
6. Start mysql on xampp

I hope it worked